# Try to add dynamic drop-down to datatable column but it's append only on front page of table

Tags: javascript, datatable

Try to add dynamic drop-down to datatable column but it's append only on front page of table.

```
$('.classname'). append ('<option>'+value+'<option>)
```

Comment: More information required...

Comment: What data table? This one: https://datatables.net/ ? What is the html? You can right click and select inspect then right click the table and select copy => copy outer html. If you post the html and let us know where you'd like the option added them maybe someone can help you.